# Cannot get select into to work

Tags: mysql, select, select-into

I have a database `squid` with a table `configs`.

I am trying to get the configs table `into a different database [testsquid] on the same host`.

Here is what I've tried:

```
select * into testsquid.configs from squid.configs;
```

I tried first without creating the configs table in testsquid, and then I actually created the `configs` table in `testsquid`.

**I am trying to get the configs table from squid into the new database testsquid. I decided not to use mysql dump because it locks the table.**

What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the table schemas are equal you can try:

```
insert into testsquid.configs
    select * from squid.configs;
```

If the new table does not exist yet create it with:

```
create table testsquid.configs like squid.configs;
```

**Update:**

I am not sure if insert-select also locks the table. To keep the locking time short you could create a similar temporary table with memory engine without any indexes. Copy the data into the temp table and after that from the temp table into the physical one.

Comment: ok and how do i get the data into the new testsquid configs table?

Comment: Use the first query to transfer data.